# three.js Cone rotation from 2 points and radius

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I am drawing a cone by parameters from xml. Is it possible to rotate the cone knowing the radius, the coordinates of the top vertex and the center of the base? example xml coords="-3,-6,0;2.5,7,0;" radius=“10” [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYn8y.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
// v1  - base center, v2 - cone's pinnacle
let h = v1.distanceTo(v2);
let g = new THREE.ConeGeometry( radius, h);
g.translate(0, h * 0.5, 0); // base to 0
g.rotateX(Math.PI * 0.5); // align along Z-axis
let m = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(); // or any other material
let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
o.position.copy(v1);
o.lookAt(v2);
scene.add(o);
```